# Unusual behavior of ternary operator?

Tags: c, ternary-operator

i was just playing around with the ternary operator in my c class today. And found this odd behavior.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
main()
{
        int x='0' ? 1 : 2;
        printf("%i",x);
}
```

`returns 1` as expected.But

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
main()
{
        int x='0'==true ? 1 : 2;
        printf("%i",x);
}
```

`returns 2` while i expect it to `return 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of '0' is not zero, it is whatever integer value encodes the digit '0' on your system. Typically 48 (in encodings borring [from ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/)), which is then not equal to `true` when interpreted as an integer, which is 1.

So the first of your code lines is equivalent to

```
int x = (48 != 0) ? 1 : 2;
```

which clearly evaluates to `1`. The second is

```
int x = (48 == 1) ? 1 : 2;
```

which just as clearly evaluates to `2`.

Comment: This would be why a good compiler with a warning for "condition is always true/false" is handy. If the compiler didn't warn for this, it is either poorly configured or poorly made.

Comment: @Lundin: I disagree. There are plenty of cases where always-true or always-false expressions arise due to use of preprocessor macros and/or use of `if` instead of `#ifdef` for conditional compilation, in which case "condition is always X" warnings are usually spurious and mask real warnings that get lost between them.

Answer (score 1):

That's because (assuming ASCII) `'0'` represents the integer `0x30`, i.e. `48`, and `true` represents the integer `1`. So they're not equal.

In C, any nonzero value is considered true, but `true` itself is `1`, and `1` is what you get from any built-in Boolean test (for example, `0 == 0` is `1`).

Comment: (+1) This is why you will often see the idiom `!!foo` instead of `foo == true` to generate a bool indicating if `foo` has a nonzero value.

Comment: `'0'` does not get promoted to int; it inherently has type `int`.

Comment: @R.: Good point, thank you. And the same is true of `true`, which is defined to expand to the integer constant `1`. So there's really no type-promotion going on here at all. I've updated my answer accordingly. (Thanks again!)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are confusing `'\0'` and `'0'`

The value of the character constant

```
'\0'
```

is always `0` in C.

The value of the character constant

```
'0'
```

is implementation defined and depends on the character set. For ASCII, it is `0x30`.

Also note that the macro `true` is defined to the value `1` and not `0`.

Answer (score 0):

`true` is defined as 1. `'0'` in ASCII is 0x30 which is not equal to 1.

Therefore the condition `'0'==true` is not true.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `'0' != true`.   The boolean value gets promoted to an integer type and is equal to 1 whereas `'0'` is equal to 48

Answer (score 0):

`'0'` does not equal `true`, so the result of `'0'==true` is 0 (false). This is assigned to `x` and passed to the ternary operator, giving the result you see.

If you intended something else, you should use brackets to clarify the order of precedence you want, or break your code up into multiple statements.